# Confusion regarding the notation of associated operator of a PDE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, notation

I'm given the following PDE: $$u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u^3=0$$ My [source](https://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%201/Exercise%201/StraussPDEch1s1p01.pdf) says that the associated operator is $$L:=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+u^2$$ which is arrived at simply by factoring the common term $u$ and thinking of the operator as left multiplying the function.$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u+u^3=\left (\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+u^2 \right )u=Lu=0$$
Is this correct? In general how do I find and write the associated operator of a PDE? Do I simply do as  my source does and just factor out the $u$? For eg. is  the operator in $$Lu=u_x+u_y+1$$ given by $$L=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{u}$$ as given [here](https://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%201/Exercise%202/StraussPDEch1s1p02.pdf)?

Comment: It's not linear because of the $u^3$ term

Comment: @Dylan My source of confusion is how to write the operator. The linearity part I've understood and since it wasn't relevant, I've removed it from the question.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the linearization? My first thought would be something like a Newton method, perhaps using a Fourier-transform in solving the associated linear (system of) equation(s)?

Comment: @LutzL I'm going through my first introduction to PDE through Strauss and he discusses linear operators. The solutions I found [here](https://www.stemjock.com/strausspde2e.htm) indicate that operators can be thought of as if they are left multiplying the function. I want to know, in general, given a PDE how do I correctly represent the associated operator, as I've mentioned in the examples. This is a very basic beginner's question regarding correct notation.

Comment: You only get linear operators for the linear parts of the equation. You could do something like decomposing the equation as $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+3a^2u=r$ where $r=3a^2u-u^3$ is bounded by $2a^3$ on the interval $u\in[-2a,2a]$. Then treat the first equation as a linear PDE and after solving it update $r$, then start again. This iteration might converge towards the exact solution. Instead of a constant $a$ you could also use a previous approximate solution $u_k$, then this gets close to a (simplified) Newton method.

Comment: The source you cite uses rather ambiguous notation. You cannot simply "factor" the term $\partial^2_t - \partial^2_x + u^2$, as it will still depend on the function $u$. The "operator" should be an object which is a priori independent of the function: it should be an object which takes a function $u$ and maps it to a new function $f$.

Comment: Remaining in your context. Perhaps it is better to consider the "operator" $Lu = (\partial^2_t - \partial^2_x) u + f(u)$, where $f(x) = x^3$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This allows you to see why exactly the resulting equation is nonlinear, and how you may proceed in linearizing it (as suggested in the previous comments).

Comment: @bgsk Yes, breaking it down like this makes sense and makes it easy to see the non linearity. I was really confused by how he just factored out the $u$. Could you paste these comments as an answer so I can give you the bounty? Also, could you have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108896/numerical-analysis-and-differential-equations-book-recommendations-focusing-on-t) and recommend some books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As indicated by the OP, I will regroup my comments as an answer.*

The source notes you cite make use of rather ambiguous/confusing notation. Indeed, one cannot simply "factor out" the term $\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2 + u^2$ and call it "the operator", as this object clearly depends on the function $u$. The operator should be an object which is a priori independent of the function: it takes a "function" $u$ as input and yields another "function" $g$ as output.

In relation to your actual question. I believe it is better to consider the "operator" $Nu = (\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2)u + f(u)$, where $f(x) = x^3$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It is now clear that the operator $N$ is nonlinear, and the linear and nonlinear parts are moreover explicitly split. 
For futher reference, the linear operator $L = \partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2$ is called the *wave operator* (also called the *d'Alembertian*), as it is the governing linear operator in the *wave equation*
\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2 u - \partial_t^2 u = 0.
\end{equation}
Hence the equation associated to the "operator" you were considering is the *nonlinear wave equation*
\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2 u - \partial_t^2 u + u^3 = 0.
\end{equation}